# Is it possible to reduce this algebraic expression $\frac{(2x+y)(x-y) }{ (2x-y)(x+y)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to reduce this expression further?

$$ \frac{(2x+y)(x-y) }{ (2x-y)(x+y) } .$$

Comment: @Rajeev: I don't think so!

Comment: The numerator and denominator have no common factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $\frac{(2x+y)(x-y)}{(2x-y)(x+y)}$-parentheses, please- you can write it as $\frac{2x^2-xy-y^2}{2x^2+xy-y^2}=1-\frac{2xy}{2x^2+xy-y^2}$  Is either one a reduction?  It is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: yes, I meant this expression only. This one is interesting. Any other reductions?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be further reduced. However it can also be written as (2x^2 -xy - y^2)/(2x^2 + xy - y^2)